# Ruby : hydrate hash values from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an ruby array like this :

```
values = ['val_a', 'val_b',..., 'val_z'] # 26 values
```

And an hash with keys

```
hash = {a: nil, b: nil, ... , z: nil} # 26 keys
```

I know that the array is sorted, and I know that keys of hash are sorted, and I know both array and hash are of same size.

How can I **elegantly** hydrate hash values so that I end up with

```
{a: 'val_a', b: 'val_b', ... , z: 'val_z'}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
hash_with_values = hash.keys.zip(values).to_h
```

Note that in some (most?) languages, keys of hashes/maps are unordered, so that would not work. That was also the case for Ruby < 1.9, but, from then on, they are guaranteed to be ordered (insertion order).

Answer (score 4):

Since Ruby 2.4.0 you can do the following:

```
hash.transform_values.with_index { |v,i| values[i] }
```

Using [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), the intent is clear. Its dangerous counterpart [`Hash#transform_values!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21) is also available.

Comment: Nice naming. transform_values is very clear about the intent.